# NullPointer Exception from PluginManager - Creating a custom Apache Cordova Plugin Echo.java

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to create a sample plug in from existing Echo plugin. I have been getting the errors below:

```
W/System.err(1894): java.lang.NullPointerException: cls == null
W/System.err(1894):     at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:489)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:167)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:120)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
W/System.err(1894):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(1894):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/System.out(1894): Error adding plugin .
W/System.err(1894): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:169)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:120)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
W/System.err(1894):     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
W/System.err(1894):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(1894):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err(1894):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Below are my files:

Echo.java

```
package com.gerald.example.sampleecho;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView)     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        Log.d("SAMPLE_ECHO", "initializing");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.d("SAMPLE_ECHO", action);
        if(action.equals("echo")){
            String message = args.getString(0);
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext){
        Log.d("SAMPLE_ECHO", "Echoing...");
        if(message != null && message.length()>0){
                callbackContext.success(message);
        }else{
                callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string      argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin.xml is shown below

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="com.gerald.example.sampleecho.echo"
version="1.2.2">

<name>SampleEcho</name>

<description>Echoes stuff</description>
<author>Oyudo Gerald</author>
<js-module src="www/echo.js" name="echo" >
    <clobbers target="myEcho"/>
</js-module>
<engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version="4.0.2"/>
</engines>
<!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Echo"
               value="com.gerald.example.sampleecho.Echo"/>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/com/gerald/example/sampleecho/Echo.java"
                target-dir="src/com/gerald/example/sampleecho" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

and the HTML code

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HelloWorld!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onBodyLoad(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);
        }
        function onDeviceReady(){
             br = "<br />";         
             //Get the appInfo DOM element        
              var element = document.getElementById("appInfo");         
              ////Replace it with specific information about the device         
              ////running the application         
              element.innerHTML = 'Cordova Version: ' +            
                      device.cordova + br +            
                      'Platform: ' + device.platform + br +          
                      'Model: ' + device.model + br +           
                      'OS Version: ' + device.version;        

        }
        function doEcho(){
             myEcho.echo("Plugin installed successfully", function(message){
                  alert(message);
              });
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>This is a sample Cordova application</p>
        <p id ="appInfo">
            waiting for cordova initialization to complete
        </p>
        <button onclick="doEcho();">Please Echo</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using cordova version 4.0.2 and JDK 8. 
There's no part of the stacktrace that references my code, so I don't even know where to start. Where did I go wrong?

I ran the android project in eclipse debug mode and i noticed that a string representation of my plugin class was passed null to CordovaWebViewImpl and down to PluginManager, I guess thats how the error came about. The new question is why is the pluginEntry for my plugin null when passed from CordovaInterface to the CordovaWebViewImpl via init() method?

Answer (score 2):

and... after a whole day of trying, I finally found out through studying the ConfigXMLParser that the feature format for the plugin below cannot be read.

```
<feature name="Echo"
           value="com.gerald.example.sampleecho.Echo"/>
```

instead use the following:

```
<feature name="Echo">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.gerald.example.sampleecho.Echo" />
</feature>
```